# How to enable the 'Updates' button in the Publish tab in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, clickonce, publish

Regarding publishing a WPF application in Visual Studio 2013: I'm trying to enable the 'Updates' button in the Publish tab. The reason I'm trying to do this is in order to manually set some of the properties (which after googling etc. I feel I need to access) so I can set the click-once installation to always update. I don't know why the 'Updates' button is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Set the install mode to:
   The application is available offline as well(launchable from the start menu)

That will enable the updates button.

Note: If you're always running online, then it will always check for updates.